# How do you display the input entered through a do while loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I'm working on a program that prompts a user for an indefinite number of student names and number grades. The program is supposed to stop prompting a user for input when the user enters -1. Once this occurs, a grade report will be displayed showing each student grade, the mimimum points, the maximum points, and the average.

Here's an example of what it should look like:

```
Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: Victoria T.
Enter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: 88
Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: Jared S.
Enter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: 93
Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: Jaheem
Enter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: 75
Enter the student's name or [-1] to quit: -1

Class Grading Report

Victoria T.: B
Jared S.: A
Jaheem: C

Minimum: 75.0
Maximum: 93.0
Average: 64.0
```

So far I've figured how to gather the input via a do-while loop, but now I'm trying to figure out how to print out all of the input that I have entered. I know there are other factors such as computing the maximum and minimum numbers as well as converting numerical grades to letter grades, but I just want to figure out how to print out the input that I enter in.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CreateGradeReport {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String studentName = "";
    int studentGrade = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's name or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentName = input.nextLine();
        if (studentName.equals("-1")){
            break;
            }
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentGrade = input.nextInt();
        if(studentGrade == -1){
            break;
            }
        String dummy = input.nextLine();
        }
    while(!studentName.equals("-1") && studentGrade != -1);
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to use `System.out.print`/`println` just like you do for the prompt.  Maybe with a `String.format` to control the formatting of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to save the details entered in a suitable data structure first. You could create a seperate class having the fields for the student's name and grade as follows:

```
public class StudentDetails {

        public String studentName;
        public int studentGrade;

        public StudentDetails (String studentName , int studentGrade){
            this.studentName  = studentName;
            this.studentGrade  = studentGrade;
        }       
    }
```

Then you can perhaps use an ArrayList of this object to save all your data this way:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CreateGradeReport {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String studentName = "";
    int studentGrade = 0;
    public ArrayList<StudentDetails> studentsDetailsList= new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's name or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentName = input.nextLine();
        if (studentName.equals("-1")){
            break;
            }
        System.out.print("\nEnter the student's grade or [-1] to quit: ");
        studentGrade = input.nextInt();
        if(studentGrade == -1){
            break;
            }
        // Add your data by invoking the constructor of your newly created
        // class above and add it to the list.
        studentsDetailsList.add(new StudentDetails(studentName, studentGrade)); 
        String dummy = input.nextLine();
        }
    while(!studentName.equals("-1") && studentGrade != -1);
    }
    
    // Print your data from this list
    for(StudentDetails sd : studentsDetailsList){
     System.out.println(sd.studentName + ", " + sd.studentGrade);
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using an array list or a separate class?